# Detect if MCU is ESP8266 or ESP32

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I'm coding a library which handles sleep procedures.

Since I'm using both ESP826 and ESP32, which uses different sleep commands ( and WiFi ), I'm looking for a way to detect the MCU, while NOT using a boolean flag that indicates so.

Guy

Comment: `#if defined(ESP8266)`, `#if defined(ESP32)`

Comment: how could you use a boolean flag? the code for esp32 would not compile on esp8266 and vice versa

Comment: @Juraj the part that code differs, I need the flag for.

Comment: you have in the question "while NOT using a boolean flag that indicates so." so you exclude a not existing option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take this to mean that you do not want to have to ask *the user* of the code to configure a boolean flag.

The ESP8266 Arduino package provides `-DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DESP8266`
command-line options these while calling g++.  These effectively `#define` feature test macros as though they were at the beginning of the source code.

For ESP32 it does likewise with `-DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32 -DESP32`

You could perform tests in your code such as:

```cpp
#if defined (ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266)
// do one thing
#elif defined(ESP32)
// do another
#else
#error Architecture unrecognized by this code.
#endif
```

There are likely also macros like these that are predefined by the xtensa g++ compiler.